# How to get array list of maps from Firebase with ModelClass

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**SOLUTION ADDED BELOW**

I would like to model this Firebase document format with in my ServiceModel which it is in SalonModel.

Actually, I can model whole fields for SalonModel but whenever I tried to model ServiceModel it is not working.

Firebase document screenShot:

[image]

Here is some part of SalonModel:

```
class SalonModel {
 String? uid;
 String? name;
SalonServices? salonServices;
SalonModel({this.uid, this.name, this.salonServices})

factory SalonModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return SalonModel(
      uid: map['uid'],
      name: map['name'],
      salonServices: map['salonServices'] != null
          ? SalonServices.fromMap(map['salonServices'])
          : null,
    );


}
```

And here is my SalonServicesClass:

```
class SalonServices {
  String? serviceName;
  String? serviceDescription;
  bool? isActive;
  int? servicePrice;
  int? serviceDiscount;
  SalonServices({
    this.serviceName,
    this.serviceDescription,
    this.isActive,
    this.servicePrice,
    this.serviceDiscount,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'serviceName': serviceName,
      'serviceDescription': serviceDescription,
      'isActive': isActive,
      'servicePrice': servicePrice,
      'serviceDiscount': serviceDiscount,
    };
  }

  factory SalonServices.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return SalonServices(
      serviceName: map['serviceName'],
      serviceDescription: map['serviceDescription'],
      isActive: map['isActive'],
      servicePrice: map['servicePrice']?.toInt(),
      serviceDiscount: map['serviceDiscount']?.toInt(),
    );
  }
}
```

And with this fucntion, I am modeling these fields:

```
Future<SalonModel> fetchMyDatas(String uid) async {
    var doc =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('salons').doc(uid).get();

    Map<String, dynamic>? docData = doc.data();
    return SalonModel.fromMap(docData!);
  }
```

Then this function returning me this error:

> Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type
> 'Map<String, dynamic>'

If we go to where the exception by thrown, we'll see this line is not working in SalonModel.fromMap:

```
 salonServices: map['salonServices'] != null
          ? SalonServices.fromMap(map['salonServices'])
          : null,
```

What can I do in this situation ?

***UPDATE***

I can't map it. There is no option.
[image]

[image]

***HERE IS MY SOLUTION***

In SalonModel class;

```
  List<SalonServices>? salonServices;
```

Then inside of SalonModel.fromMap method:

```
...
     salonServices: json['salonServices'] == null
                ? null
                : List<SalonServices>.from(
                    json['salonServices'].map((x) => SalonServices.fromMap(x)))
```

And our fetchMyDatas works well finally.

Comment: You declared `ServiceModel? salonServices;`, but I don't see a `ServiceModel` class anywhere. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, it's just miswrite. I wanted to not adding whole code and typed shortly. Anyway if it was wrong in project, we can't build it with an error. Edited the question sir.

Comment: Please don't add the solution to the question itself. Instead, post the solution as a self-answer below, explaining what you changed and why that solved the problem. Self-answers are encouraged on Stack Overflow. --- Also note that your solution is pretty much what I pointed out in my answer with some syntax changes. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thank you. Of course there is a little bit change. All my best wishes with you sir <3

Answer (score 2):

This mapping seems wrong:

```
SalonServices? salonServices;
```

Since you have an array of objects in the `salonServices` in the database, you should map that to an array/list of `SalonServices` in your model class too:

```
List<SalonServices> salonServices;
```

And then I'd expect something like this for the mapping code:

```
salonServices: map['salonServices'] != null
    ? map['salonServices'].map((e) => SalonServices.fromMap(e))
    : null,
```

The `e` here would point to the the child maps under the `salonServices` node in the database one by one. If you get an error about its type, you might need to cast `e` to a `Map`.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. But still doesn't work. There is no .map property for ```map['salonServices']``` part. Yet, I added it by typing (somehow didn't return an error). But still can't handling with this problem. Also, I updated question with secrenshots.

Comment: Did you already run in the debugger and check what data type `map['salonServices']` gives you?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, SalonServices>?'  This is what's wrong in terminal.

Comment: I found a solution myself. Thanks for efforts sir.

Answer (score 0):

***HERE IS MY SOLUTION***

In SalonModel class;

```
  List<SalonServices>? salonServices;
```

Then inside of SalonModel.fromMap method:

```
...
     salonServices: json['salonServices'] == null
                ? null
                : List<SalonServices>.from(
                    json['salonServices'].map((x) => SalonServices.fromMap(x)))
```

And our fetchMyDatas works well finally.